# $('html body').animate({ scrollTop: not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

Scrolling Page with jQuery does not work in Firefox (works fine in Chrome) 
When I click on the menu items the page should scroll to the given section of the menu and it works only in Chrome.

I wonder what is wrong with my code https://jsfiddle.net/4yrorr9k/

```
function setBindings() {
    $('nav a, #slidebox a').click(function(e){
    event.preventDefault();

    var sectionID = e.currentTarget.id + 'Section';

    $('html body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#' + sectionID).offset().top}, 500)
  });
}
```

I presume it has to do with ScrollTop hence the title of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there is an issue, event is not declared (in firefox event is not global) which can be seen in the developer console. The issue which was causing the scroll top to not to work in firefox is the selector for animate in your set setBindings function.

```
$('html body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#' + sectionID).offset().top}, 500)
});
```

change this to

```
$('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#' + sectionID).offset().top}, 500)
});
```

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/2ynbto8x/

Comment: So instead of event.preventDefault(); there should be e.preventDefault();

Comment: @AKAI yes , you are right but it entirely depends upon what variable name you are passing in the function(variable) . it variable is event then event.preventDefault() if its e then e.preventDefault()

Comment: aaah , ok,, now I get it

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of little things here, the main one being your jQuery selector of ('html body') (i.e. a body inside an html) - you need it to be either/or so put a comma in between.

This is because Chrome scrolls the body element, Firefox scrolls the HTML element.

Also, firefox throws an error as you are trying to use the undeclared 'event' variable, so you need to replace this with 'e'.

Also, as your 'top' result can be fractional, I'd parse it down to an int, and then specify that this is a pixel position, so:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: parseInt($('#' + sectionID).offset().top) + 'px'}, 500)
});
```

Amended jsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/kitkit/jftfdq70/2/